# Gap between foundation and wrap

Tags: foundation, waterproofing, house-wrap

I recently purchased a new house in Ontario, Canada.

The grading will be completed in the following months.

During a walk around the house, I noticed gaps between the foundation walls and the wrapping. How much of an issue is this? Should this be fixed by the builder?

Thank you.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What “wrapping” are you referring to...? The fabric in the dirt? Can you dig down 3”-4” and see if it’s against the wall or extends horizontally out into the yard about 12” or so? Or ask them what it’s for...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a water proofing hard'ish plastic called air gap waterproofing membrane, commonly referred to as dimple board. it's not a part of the vapour barrier and it's primary function is to stop water from the water table entering the foundation. It's is good practice to run that it up higher so that it's flush with the finished grade upon completion. The missing morter is actually a requirement to allow condensation for the space between the wood structure and the brick to dry or drip out in extreme cases. The builder will likely do nothing because any landscaping should always be sloped away from your house anyway. I'm from Toronto and see this stuff almost daily. I did have to look up the official name as everyone just refers to it as dimple board.

Answer (score 0):

If your referring to the barrier between the slab and the ground the important part of it is under the slab. I would be more concerned with the mortar missing on the bottom row of bricks. There is one gap that looks like has none. That is either a drain or an inlet or shouldn't be open.

Comment: That “mortar missing on the bottom row of bricks” is NOT a problem...it’s a weep hole. They’re evenly spaced around the building.

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not mention a basement I would say that is a vapor barrier,  in some areas this will greatly extend the life of the cement work and reduce the moisture coming up through the concrete. Nothing to worry about there in my opinion.